# Can i do an update from select with ExecuteUpdate in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF7 there is a new [ExecuteUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) function to do updates on a table without retrieving the data from the server first.
Is it possible to do an [update from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server) with this method in any way where it is using data from another table?
To be more concrete can i express this SQL in EF:

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following query updates table with values from joined table.

```cs
var query = 
    from a in context.TableA
    join b in context.TableB on a.id equals b.id
    where a.col3 == "cool"
    select new { a, b };

query.ExecuteUpdate(s => 
    s.SetProperty(x => x.a.col1, x => x.b.col1)
     .SetProperty(x => x.a.col2, x => x.b.col2)
);
```